# List a collection of a Class in Java

Tags: java, list, class, object

I have in java a User Class:

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String name,email,password;
private Collection<Book> books;


public User(String name, String email, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public Collection<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(Collection<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


}
```

I'm omitting the notations of persistence

I have in java a list of Users, and each User has a Collection of Books,

Now i need print each User with his collection of books

And i have a DAO with a method that return all users of my database

I am intenting with:

```
private List<User> userList = UserDAO.getAll();
```

And now i have all my users.

And now to get the list of Books of my User i have this:

```
     private Collection <Book> = user.getBooksCollection();
```

and in this way i have the collection of Mno but of a specific user

And i need print each User with his respective Collection of Books (But only the name of the book)

Because my Book class has various attributes and i need only each User with the name of the Book.

But i do not know how do it.

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to use such a structure? Why not use a linked list?

Comment: `for (User user : userList) { System.out.println(user.getName()); for (Book book : user.getBooksCollection()) { System.out.println(book.getName()); } }`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
for(User user : userList)
{
    System.out.println(user.getName());                 // XXX
    for(Book book : user.getBooksCollection())
    {
        System.out.println("    " + book.getTitle());   // XXX
    }
}
```

Where the lines marked as `XXX` have made up method names you'd need to substitute in for whatever you're calling them.

It'd print a list like:

```
John Smith
    Book Title A
    Book Title B
Bob Smith
    Book Title A
    Book Title C
```

But using the `Collection` interface seems pretty odd.  Are you sure you can't go deeper down the stack?  Say, with `List`?

Answer (score 1):

Lookup an example of a for ... each loop, you can use that to iterate through your collection of Users. Then for every user, print the user stuff, retrieve the book collection, and use a for ... each loop to iterate through the users books. If you do it right you get 2 nested for loops. Good Luck!